# React - Rename file attachment dynamically in browser

Tags: reactjs, attachment, file-rename, right-click

I have a page in my React application that contains a set of files as attachments(something similar to email attachments on gmail). I am trying to rename the files once they have been added to the page and not while uploading the file from 'choose files'. Any inputs would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you post any example ? How are you managing your attachments that are selected for upload ?

Comment: I was thinking something like right-click on file name and edit the name..something like that works on our local desktops for file rename.